# How to resize (not reshape) 2D tensor?

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow, resize, tensor

I have tensor of shape [2400, 2400]. I want to resize it to [1200, 1200].
Precisely,

> I just want to replicate [resizem](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/resizem.html) function in Matlab.

** I am aware of the fact that tenforflow has some resize functions for images. but all of them take a 4-D tensor as input.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could first reshape to a 4D tensor by adding empty dimensions, and then apply the default resize functions, and reshape the end result again if necessary.

Comment: I tried. I convert **[2400, 2400]** to **[1, 1, 2400, 2400]** and then applied **alfa = tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor(alfa, [1200, 1200])** and got the a **[1, 1200, 1200, 2400]** shaped tensor, but i want a **[1200, 1200]**

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [`tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_nearest_neighbor) before trying? It expects the input image to be of size `[batch, height, width, channels]`, so your dimensions for the input should rather be [1, 1200, 1200, 1].

Comment: in that case, alfa = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(alfa, 2), 0) **# tf.shape(alfa) = [1, 2400, 2400, 1]**
alfa = tf.image.resize_nearest_neighbor(alfa, [1200, 1200]) **# now, tf.shape(alfa) = [1, 1200, 1200, 1]** but i want [1200, 1200]

Comment: alfa = tf.squeeze(tf.squeeze(alfa, 3), 0) gives me [1200, 1200] but i dont know if its the correct answer !!

Comment: Yes, that's the correct answer. `squeeze` removes all dimensions that have value 1 (which also means you need to call ti only once, not twice)

Comment: A 2D tensor is a matrix, is there any problem in using `interp2`?

Comment: Just like @Guto, I was under the impression that you wanted to replicate this in MATLAB, the only indication otherwise is the Python syntax in the comments. Please use tags appropriately. If you have a Python question, don't tag as MATLAB!